# OAuth2 with SPA and API

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I want to implement Single Sign On in Angular 5 SPA which uses ASP.NET Core API. I have OAuth2 server provided by the company. 
What I want to achieve is to allow access to the application only to authorized users, who have to pass through SSO process. I want to display content of the SPA only to authorized users and allow to access API resources only by them (users with correct `access_tokens`), too.

I do not know what should be the correct approach for this requirement. I was considering:

1. Implicit grant flow - from my SPA `myspa.com:4200` I am invoking `mycompanyauthserver.com/Authorize` to obtain authorization code.
   With that and client_id in Angular app I am invoking `mycompanyauthserver.com/Token` to obtain `access token`. I save it in localstorage. Now, I can send this `access token` with request to my API `(myapi.com:5000)`, but how to check in API if this token is correct? I do not have endpoint on OAuth server to do it. Also, how to check on SPA if access code is correct and not manipulated by user?
2. Another approach I see is to invoke from SPA some endpoint in my API which will invoke `mycompanyauthserver.com/Authorize` and then `mycompanyauthserver.com/Token` and then API will have access_token and return it to SPA. Then, I can easily check while sending request from SPA to API if the `access_code` is the same. Is the right approach or am I missing something?

Comment: You can use authguard for authorization....

Comment: I am using it anyway, but it does answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Does your SPA really run on `localhost:4200?` This would make it a native application, where you could possibly make use of other grant types like Auth code with PKCE. Or is `localhost:4200` just a local/dev version of your SPA?

If your app is a SPA, and will be served html and javascript from an external web resource, then yes the implicit grant is optimised for this scenario.

But even so, if your external web resource (which serves up the SPA) can also provide and register a redirect endpoint which can interact with `mycompanyauthserver.com/Token` endpoint, then you can use the authorisation code grant and return the access_token from your server-side redirection endpoint back to your browser - similar to what you suggest in your option 2.

I'm not sure there's a correct approach.

I've seen SPAs use both approaches. Option 2 involves more server-side code to manage tokens. Option 1 simplifies getting a token but won't give you a long-lived/refresh token. Take your pick :)

Comment: yes, it is dev version only: SPA is on localhost:4200 and APi on localhost:5000

Comment: In case of option  with implicit grant, can you refer to my questions: how to verify that access token on API side and also if I store the access token in localstorage, how to check the corecctness of this token too, e.g. when user change it and we do not want him to login with changed token

Comment: you've changed your question a bit! What you describe as the implicit grant in option 1, is infact the authorisation code grant with public client. Implicit grant does not use token endpoint. Your API should be able to check the access_token has not been tampered with by using the public key of the authorisation server's signing key and verifying the signature. Your SPA doesn't need to do this as the API must verify the access token.

Comment: `by using the public key of the authorisation server's signing key and verifying the signature.` What if I do not have access to that?

Comment: It can depend on the type of token - for `value` type tokens (e.g. JWT) then generally the signature should be verified and you'll need access to the public key. For `reference` type tokens any tampering would invalidate the reference so it couldn't be used by the API against the auth server. Maybe ask the team who manage your auth server how your API can trust the token?